# What is the point of designing Lua C APIs?

Tags: c, lua

I am a newbie of `Lua`. After studying some `Lua C APIs` examples, I am a little confused.

I can see the `Lua C API` is used for processing `Lua` scripts:

```
......
lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);
luaL_loadfile(L, argv[1]);
lua_call(L, 0, 0);
lua_close(L);
......
```

Or calling a `Lua` function from `C` code:

```
/* calling f("hello", 4.5) */
lua_getglobal(L, "f");
lua_pushstring(L, "hello");
lua_pushnumber(L, 4.5);
lua_call(L, 2, 1);
```

So what is the point of designing `Lua C APIs`? If just do these functions, I think call `lua` program is enough, no need to use `Lua C APIs`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many situations when calling Lua functions from a program written in another language is better than calling a Lua script.

- When you distribute a program that does useful things, it's easier to link the relevant part of the Lua library in and do things within your program than to bundle the entire Lua system and install that for every user of your program. Not everybody wants that much extra code, some users will already have Lua installed, you have to keep the user's Lua separate from your bundled Lua, etc.
- Bundling the entire language can take up a lot of space. Linking only some functions in can make the resulting package of your program much smaller.
- It's more efficient not to create a new process every time you want to use the functionality implemented in Lua. If this is several times per second, the speed-up will be substantial.
- Passing data to a new process and receiving return data is complicated; you have to either set up inter-process communication via shared memory, pipes, ports or something similar, or parse the STDOUT of the external program. That works fine for small values, but not wel lat all for large, structured data.

Note that not all of these reasons always apply. There are many use cases where *none* apply, and bundling the scripting language *is* in fact the better solution. But there certainly are other cases where bundling would be overkill, and that's why the programmatic API exists.

Answer (score 8):

Lua is not only -and not mainly- a standalone interpreter program (`/usr/bin/lua` on my Linux/Debian desktop) of the Lua scripting language, but **Lua is mostly a *library* to *embed* an interpreter into** (existing) **applications** (e.g. `luatex` is embedding Lua inside `tex`).

This is the main strength of Lua, to be *embeddable* in your application. Lua was originally designed for that purpose. So you have some existing application, and you can (with not too much efforts) embed the Lua interpreter *library* inside your application to enable some parts of it to be scriptable by Lua.

This is explained in the chapter [§24 – An Overview of the C API](http://www.lua.org/pil/24.html), which starts with:

> Lua is an embedded language. That means that Lua is not a stand-alone package, but a library that can be linked with other applications so as to incorporate Lua facilities into these applications.
>
> You may be wondering: If Lua is not a stand-alone program, how come we have been using Lua stand alone through the whole book? The solution to this puzzle is the Lua interpreter (the executable lua). This interpreter is a tiny application (with less than five hundred lines of code) that uses the Lua library to implement the stand-alone interpreter. This program handles the interface with the user, taking her files and strings to feed them to the Lua library, which does the bulk of the work (such as actually running Lua code).
>
> This ability to be used as a library to extend an application is what makes Lua an extension language. At the same time, a program that uses Lua can register new functions in the Lua environment; such functions are implemented in C (or another language) and can add facilities that cannot be written directly in Lua. This is what makes Lua an extensible language.
>
> These two views of Lua (as an extension language and as an extensible language) correspond to two kinds of interaction between C and Lua. In the first kind, C has the control and Lua is the library. The C code in this kind of interaction is what we call application code. In the second kind, Lua has the control and C is the library. Here, the C code is called library code. Both application code and library code use the same API to communicate with Lua, the so called C API.

---

In that case you need to bind (i.e. wrap) some of your routines as primitive functions called by Lua scripts, and you also need to be able to run Lua (e.g. by interpreting some bytecode or script).

So the point of designing some Lua C API is to be able to use Lua to script some existing application or software (and not mainly to extend a standalone Lua interpreter with something else, even if that is possible thru plugins loaded in [loadlib.c](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/loadlib.c.html), which gets called by [require](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-require) ...)

Notice also that embedding an interpreter inside your application is a very strong architectural software design decision (that IMHO you should make quite early).